# Как на домене показывать другой сайт?

Tags: php, cname

Не знаю правильно ли сформировал заголовок вопроса, попытаюсь объяснить что я хочу получить.

Есть домен (или поддомен), например domain.ru,и я хочу(например прописаны ему CNAME?) чтобы перейдя на этот домен мы видели сайт который находиться на другом домене. И чтобы при этом другой домен понимал какой CNAME у domain.ru, это нужно для того чтобы идентифицировать domain.ru,и показывать ему соответствующий контент.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: "этот другой домен" - свой или чужой?

Comment: Если свой, то `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: @Ипатьев "этот другой домен" это мой домен. А можно подробнее пожалуйста? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] вроде понятно, но как заставить domain.ru смотреть на "этот другой домен" с помощью CNAME?

Comment: куда подробнее-то? второй домен тупо указывает на айпи первого, без всяких cname. в конфиге веб-сервера прописаны тоже оба - это очевидно. "чтобы идентифицировать domain.ru,и показывать ему соответствующий контент." - $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] в коде

Comment: @Ипатьев но что если нужно именно через CNAME?

Comment: не понял. что значит "нужно именно через CNAME"? Звучит как "А обязательно штаны через ноги снимать? Мне нужно именно через голову!". А куда будет в таком случае указывать А запись?